# Value of input[type="button"] change to copyable text through css?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the input[type="button"] to text as I want to copy the text inside the value of the input button means If I drag the text of the the button I can easily copy that text.

Here is my code:

`<input type="button" value="TELL ME MORE">`

Is it possible to make the value of button to copy easily?

I don't want inline css I want to apply from other file.

Comment: Copy as in let user using the website copy it or you want to copy it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this css

```css
input[type="button"]{
user-select:text;}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Tell us more">
```

Comment: If you manually edit type to text (type="text") you can easily copy the text I want to customize though css..

Comment: @Sangrai can u plz more clarify what are you to say. coz I did it via CSS

Answer (score 0):

Use a css class, that way you can control in which button you want selection.

```css
/*use this to element where selection is allowed*/
.selectable{
user-select:text;}

/*use this to element where selection is not allowed*/
.notselectable{
user-select:none;}
```

```html
<html><body>
<input class = 'selectable' type="button" value='Select Me'>

<div class = 'notselectable'> Unselectable text</div>

<input class = 'notselectable' type="text" value='Css will have no effect on me I am selectable by default'>

<input class = 'notselectable' type="text" disabled = 'true' value='Even if you disable me, text can be selected '>


</body></html>
```

Comment: if you change the type button to text you can copy the text "Select me" but If user want to make it though css how can he customize that?

Comment: I would highly recommend not to use [Type=button], because it will apply to all the button elements and does not give flexibility to the designer. I am updating the snippet with some more examples.